# rails insert into model and association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I got a main table and a bezirk table.

When i insert data into my main table, i want to insert data in my bezirk table as well. And the entry i am creating in bezirk, should have the id of the main table.

Main Model:

```
class Main < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :category, :latlon
   has_one :bezirk
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :bezirk
end
```

Bezirk Model:

```
class Bezirk < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :beznr, :coordinates, :district_code, :id, :name
  belongs_to :main
end
```

And here is how i tried to do it...

```
    main = Main.new(:category => "Bezirk", :latlon => 'POINT(1,2)')
    main.save
    bezirk = main.bezirks.new(:name => 'test', :beznr => 2, :district_code => 1160, :coordinates => 'POINT(1,2)')
    bezirk.save
```

So... how am i able to insert into bezirk, the corresponding main id!? so that i have an association between two entries...

Comment: that should have worked actually (If I didn't miss anything) from what I can see. When you retrieve the bezirk main_id should be set to the id of main. If that's not what you want please be a bit more specific about the problem.

Comment: Maybe i should tell you, that i am doing this in a custom rake task? Maybe i do need to include/require bezirk? But how?

Error means: undefined method 'bezirks' for #<Main:0x....>

Comment: that because your main object doesn't have `bezirks` method. If you want to access bezirk of main, you can use `main.bezirk`, because your association name is `bezirk`, it's from `has_one :bezirk`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
# create main
main = Main.create(:category => "Bezirk", :latlon => 'POINT(1,2)')

# create bezirk belongs to main, so bezirk will have main_id, is id of main
bezirk = main.create_bezirk(:name => 'test', :beznr => 2, :district_code => 1160, :coordinates => 'POINT(1,2)')
```

Comment: could you maybe tell me, where i can read about this? because i didnt find anything about this...

Comment: okay, you can read it here: [has_one association reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_one-association-reference).